# How to find records having minimal and maximal value in group (SQL)?

Tags: sql-server

I am quite new in SQL language. For illustration purposes I have a simple table having two columns: Item, Param1.

| Item | Param1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| B | 10 |
| A | 50 |
| A | 150 |
| B | 50 |
| C | 0 |
| C | 200 |
| B | 150 |

I need to create a list of unique items having Param1 greater than 100 and at the same time having the smallest value to be 0. So the results in this case should be:

| Item |
| --- |
| A |
| C |

Selecting the unique list of items would look like this, which is a half of that what I need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Item
FROM Database
WHERE Param1 > 100
```

I would appreciate for help in creating corresponding query.
Best regards

Comment: select a.item from tablea as a where a.Param1 >100 group by a.item having min(a.Param1)=0

Comment: @Sergey Close - but the filter is applied before aggregation. Move filter to having clause as max(a.Param1) > 100. Add that as answer.

Comment: @SMor,agree.You are right

Comment: Ok, thank you for suggestions, I got the working query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with cte(Item,Param1) as
(
    SELECT 'A',     0
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B',     10
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A',     50
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A',     150 
      UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B',  50  
      UNION ALL
   SELECT 'C',  0   
      UNION ALL
   SELECT 'C',  200 
      UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B',  150  
  )
  SELECT C.Item
  FROM CTE AS C
  GROUP BY C.Item
  HAVING MIN(C.Param1)=0 AND MAX(C.Param1)>100
```

Answer (score 1):

You're half way there. You just need to additionally filter for those with 0 as minimal value. This can be done with an subselect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Item
    FROM Database
    WHERE Param1 > 100
        AND Item IN
            (
                SELECT Item
                    FROM Database
                    GROUP BY Item
                    HAVING MIN(Param1) = 0
            );
```